# Angular - Async method doesn't return a rejected promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I'm using an `async` method in component for file upload. Like this:

```
//component
uploadPhotos = async (event: Event) => {
    const upload = await this.uploadService.uploadPhotos(event, this.files, this.urls);
}
```

`UploadService` returns a `promise` with the updated files and path files after upload is called. The service is working as expected for a `promise` that reaches `resolve()` without any setbacks. However, if `reject()` is called, the code will keep going until it reaches the `resolve()` inside `reader.onload()`.

```js
// service
uploadPhotos(event: Event, oldFiles: File[], oldUrls: string[]): Promise<{files: File[], urls: string[]}> {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

          if ((files.length + oldFiles.length) > 5) {
               this.alertService.error('Número máximo de fotos permitidos é 5.');
               reject();
               // there is an error, so it reaches here first
          }
      
          for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              const exists = oldFiles.findIndex(file => file.name === files[i].name);
              if (exists === -1) {
                   if (files[i].type === 'image/png' || files[i].type === 'image/jpeg') {
                      oldFiles.push(files[i]);

                      const reader = new FileReader();
                      reader.onerror = (error: any) => {
                          this.alertService.error(`Erro ao carregar a imagem: ${error}`);
                          reject();
                      };
                      reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
                      reader.onload = () => {
                      // it reaches here after reject()
                          oldUrls.push(reader.result);
                          if (i === files.length - 1) { resolve({ files: oldFiles, urls: oldUrls }); }
                 };
            } else {
                this.alertService.error('Formato inválido. Somente imagens do formato Png, Jpeg e Jpg são permitidos.');
                reject();
            }
       }
  }
});
}
```

Is there a way to avoid that `reader.onload()` block if `reject()` is reached before `resolve()`?

Comment: Hrm, so the `load` handler is called even if there's an error, is that it? (sounds a bit odd) If so, there's a solution, but just for clarity's sake, can you confirm that?

Comment: yeah... it is called right after `reject()`

Comment: The load listener's `if (i === files.length - 1) {` test is weird (it will only ever trigger on `files[files.length - 1]` regardless of the order in which they actually get processed, I'm doubtful that the `Promise` always resolves with all `urls`?

Comment: It seems to work so far... im trying to return `resolve` after last element is added. However if something goes wrong between the process I would like to abort mission.

Comment: so, when you reject you don't want any further code to run? `reject` isn't like `return` it doesn't end function execution ... try `return reject(...)`

Comment: So even `resolve` doesnt stop the function? Im used to async node.js and its a bit easier i think, still getting used to it. Im not on pc anymore, later im going to test the solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `reject()` and `resolve()` are plain (callback) function calls. They have nothing to do with control flow, they don't stop your function. Use `return` or `if`/`else` for that.

Also, you have a loop inside your `new Promise`. If an error in one file reader happens, it has no effects on the other file readers. I recommend promisification on the innermost level instead. Then write

```
readFile(file: File): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = (error: any) => reject(error);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
// service
async uploadPhotos(event: Event, oldFiles: File[], oldUrls: string[]): Promise<{files: File[], urls: string[]}> {
    try {
        const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
        if ((files.length + oldFiles.length) > 5) {
            throw new Error('Número máximo de fotos permitidos é 5.');
        }
        const newFiles = Array.from(files).filter(newFile =>
            !oldFiles.some(oldFile => oldFile.name === newFile.name)
        );
        if (!newFiles.every(file => file.type === 'image/png' || file.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.type === 'image/jpg')) {
            throw new Error('Formato inválido. Somente imagens do formato Png, Jpeg e Jpg são permitidos.');
        }
        const newUrls = await Promise.all(newFiles.map(file =>
            this.readFile(file).catch(error => {
                throw new Error(`Erro ao carregar a imagem: ${error}`);
            })
        ));
        return {
            files: oldFiles.concat(newFiles),
            urls: oldUrls.concat(newUrls)
        };
    } catch(err) {
        this.alertService.error(err.message);
        throw new Error("something went wrong during file upload");
    }
}
```

Comment: for removing files it should work like this? `deleteImage(file: File, url: string) { this.files.splice(this.files.indexOf(file)); this.urls.splice(this.urls.indexOf(url)); }`. Let's say my array has 5 elements... when splicing just `this.urls[2]`..... `this.urls[3]` and `this.urls[4]` got removed as well... can you help me?

Comment: @James [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) takes the index and the number of elements to be deleted - so `….splice(….indexOf(…), 1)` should do it. But make sure `indexOf` does actually find the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `load` listener, then remove it in the `error` handler to ensure that the `load` listener doesn't trigger:

```
reader.onerror = (error: any) => {
  this.alertService.error(`Erro ao carregar a imagem: ${error}`);
  reader.removeEventListener('load', loadHandler);
  reject();

};
reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
const loadHandler = () => {
  oldUrls.push(reader.result);
  if (i === files.length - 1) {
    resolve({ files: oldFiles, urls: oldUrls });
  }
};
reader.addEventListener('load', loadHandler);
```